# Unable to create directory in jenkins using shell command

Tags: shell, jenkins

I am unable to create directory using shell command in jenkins.Can anyone tell me how to make one.. 
I am using the following command:

```
mkdir -p /jenkins/project/konnect
```

But I am getting the following result:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/jenkins/project/konnect’: No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: You are trying to create a directory off the root directory (/) and you probably have no permission to do that as the Jenkins user. did you mean to have a directory off the workspace? `mkdir -p jenkins/project/konnect`

Comment: Why do you want to create this folder?

Comment: I know that jenkins user has no permission to do so and even sudo is not working...Yes I meant to create thee directory off the workspace.
I want to create the directory to move certain files to a new directory where my shell commands will work...

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do this.

Jenkins automatically creates workspace for your pjroject.

otherwise if you have sudo access you can create.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/192050/how-to-run-sudo-command-with-no-password/443071#443071     - refer this post. It will solve your access issue